# I dont get push notification when the app is running in the foreground

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

so i am making an app to get notifications but it only get the notifications when i close the app, but when i try to send notifications from the FCM when the app is in the foreground it wont receive any notification, and it crashes. What's wrong? can anyone help

This is my code

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

public MyFirebaseMessagingService() {
}

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    //Check if message contains data payload
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();//get title
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();//get body
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction(); //ge

        sendNotification(title, body, click_action);

    }

    //Check if message contains a notification payload
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();//get title
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();//get body
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction(); //ge

        sendNotification(title, body, click_action);


    }
}

private void sendNotification(String title,String messageBody, String click_action) {
    Intent intent;
    if(click_action.equals("News")){
        intent = new Intent(this, NewsActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }
    else if(click_action.equals("Updates")){
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }else{
        intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    }

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

Comment: When you send notifications using console, you recieve data notifications, not contextual, or something like this.

Comment: Please add the stack trace when asking why your code is crashing.

Comment: Also add the json with you are hitting api or sending through firebase console..

Comment: If you are sending data payload, in the block entered with test `remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0`, use `remoteMessage.getData()` to obtain the data fields.

Comment: Would you please update your question with stacktrace and json?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look how you check and receive your data:

```
//Check if message contains data payload
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();//get title
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();//get body
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction(); //ge

        sendNotification(title, body, click_action);

    }
```

Replace it with `remoteMessage.getData()`.

The reason why it crashes: You checked if `getData()` is not empty. In **foreground**, both (notification and data payload) will be received in your `onMessageReceived` method (it won't crash because you can still collect the `getNotification()` data).
In **background**, the notification payload is not available and sent directly to the system tray, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Your code should look like this:

```
//Check if message contains data payload
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {

        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");//get title
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");//get body
        String click_action = remoteMessage.getData().get("click_action"); //get action, maybe you have to debug this and look for the right key

        sendNotification(title, body, click_action);

    }
```

Comment: sorry it doesnt work.. do you meant like this? 

  `if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {`
      `  remoteMessage.getData();`

   ` }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the service to the manifest?

```
<service
android:name=".MyFcmListenerService">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
```

[see the migration guide to see that you completed all necessary actions](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-gcmlistener)